# Range validation for textbox not working in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to raise validation error in an ASP.Net MVC 3 application. 
 When the user enters a number that is greater than 1000 an error message should be displayed.  with the following code on a view model it doesn't seem to be working.
 What do i need to change?

```
[Range(0, 1000, ErrorMessage = "Total number of rows to display must be between 0 to 1000")]
 public int DisplayTop { get; set; }
```

cshtml :

```
@model  Calc.Models.CountingVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reports";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_reportsLayout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Reports", "Calc", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmReport" }))
{   
 .........
  @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.DisplayTop, "1000")
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.DisplayTop)
}
```

Action Method :

```
       public ActionResult Reports(string ReportName, CalcCriteria criteria)
            {

                  if ((criteria == null) || (criteria.nId == null))
                    {
                        criteria = TempData["criteria"] as CalcCriteria;
                        TempData["criteria"] = criteria; // For reload, without this reloading the page causes null criteria.
                    }
                  ReportType c = (ReportType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ReportType), ReportName, true);
                    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    string vmJson = string.Empty;

                    switch (c)
                    {
                           .....
                            int displayTop;
                           ..........
                            case ReportType.Inventory_Counts_Report:                      
                           ..............
                            displayTop = Convert.ToInt32(Request["DisplayTop"]);
                           ........
                     return View("Counting", CountingVM);
                     default:
                            return View();
                     }
                return View(); }
```

Thanks

BB

Comment: What does your cshtml or aspx view look like?  What does your controller action look like?

Comment: You are probably not checking the ModelState in the controller...

Answer (score 1):

You also need to display the validation message:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.DisplayTop)
```

Comment: is it possible to restrict the number of character in the textboxfor. [Eg : <input type ="text" maxlength ="4">]

Comment: @BumbleBee Yes, just use [StringLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx) attribute on the property.

Comment: @BumbleBee Do you have it enabled in your web.config? Take a look [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html).

Comment: both of them are enabled in web.config.

Comment: @BumbleBee Post the rest of your view and the action method.

Comment: I posted the view and action can u pls take a look

Comment: @BumbleBee View seems OK. Can you open up Firebug and check if you are getting any JavaScript errors. You may have not added some script files.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Html.EditorFor(c => c.DisplayTop, "1000")
```

I guess, that the problem occures, becase your property is of type int, and the range is for type int, byt you are showing it in a textbox.

Also you need to add `ModelState.IsValid` in your controller. For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(YourModel model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      // Put your logic here
   }

   return View(create)
}
```