# Format and validate currency field within range in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have defined price field in my project using following way.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "\'D2\' should not be left blank and cannot contain all spaces.")]
[Range(10, 300, ErrorMessage = "\'D2\' must be within 10 and 300.")]
public System.Nullable<decimal> D2 { get; set; };
```

The issue with above code is that when user entered value 100 into textbox after that on blur event of textbox I have wrote following lines of code.

```
$('#D2').blur(function() { 
    $('#D2').formatCurrency();
});
```

When I format the textbox value like `$100.00` then it raised the error message 'D2' must be within 10 and 300. So please let me know how can I resolve the issue.

Comment: Please take the time to format your questions properly. This was pretty much unreadable

Comment: you can find the solution in this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902770/range-validation-for-textbox-not-working-in-mvc3)

Comment: A value of `$100.00` cannot be bound to a `decimal`  unless you have created a custom ModelBinder. And for the client side validation, you would need to create you own validation attribute or override the jquery validator methods